# Server Networking in android

Tags: java, android, server, device, communication

I crossed upon a game called "DUAL". 
In this game you can communicate between two devices (CO-OP) with BLUETOOTH or WIFI if the two devices are on the same network.

I'm having difficult to explain and it may sound a little bit ignorant but my question is where is the server? if the game communicates between two devices only on the same network.

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer

one of the devices is the server. or both devices update the other

Comment: Thank you, i will take a look at it.

Comment: Or they use push mechanisim using the GCM

Comment: [Connecting Devices Wirelessly](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html) and [Connect Android devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549662/connect-android-devices)